# How to format text in Google Docs using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would to like to write a script to find all specific words and format their color.

I tryied the following, but it seems it is not working:

```
function ChangeColor() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var myword = body.findText("var");

  while (myword !== null){
    var mysearch = myword.getElement().asText().setForegroundColor('#DC64DC');
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the font color of "var" in the document. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In order to search next word, it uses `findText(searchPattern, from)`.
- In order to change the color of "var", it uses `setForegroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)`.

  - In your script, the offset of start and end can be retrieved by `myword.getStartOffset()` and `myword.getEndOffsetInclusive()`, respectively.

#### Modified script :

```
function ChangeColor() {
  var searchValue = "var";
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var myword = body.findText(searchValue);

  while (myword) {
    var mysearch = myword.getElement().asText()
    mysearch.setForegroundColor(
      myword.getStartOffset(), // startOffset
      myword.getEndOffsetInclusive(), // endOffsetInclusive
      '#DC64DC' // color
    );
    var myword = body.findText(searchValue, myword); // Search next word
  }
}
```

#### References :

- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern-from)
- [setForegroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setforegroundcolorstartoffset-endoffsetinclusive-color)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.